# sql query error 1060 Duplicate Column error 'nome'

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have a problem and i need help

this is my query

```
ALTER VIEW contrato AS
SELECT formando.nome, formando.bicc, formando.nif, formando.escagr, a.designacao, gf.nome, t.nome from formando
JOIN grupo_formando gf ON formando.id = gf.formando_id
JOIN aluno al on formando.id = al.formando_id
JOIN turma t on al.turma_id = t.id
JOIN acao a on t.acao_id = a.id
```

and this is my problem: 1060 Duplicate Column error 'nome'

Anyone knows how can i solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see here any gf. To use short name of table you have to assign it first.

Comment: @Grynets I have the short name declared in the join

Comment: Have you verified that there is a column named `nome` in the `grupo_formando` table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff my field is in ortuguese but i just correct the error to english and all the question is in english

Comment: try to do this for every 'as' `JOIN grupo_formando as gf`

Comment: guys i just found the error, i have a wrong letter in the name

Comment: now i have the error 1060  Duplicate Column error 'nome'

Comment: @Grynets    ghghghghghghghghgh

Comment: If you have a duplicate column then alias the duplicate (ex: t.nome as nome2)

Answer (score 2):

The following columns in your view will have the same name:

```
select formando.nome, gf.nome, t.nome ...
```

When you call the view, how will sql know which column is nome?
You will need to give each column their own name (alias) eg:

```
select formando.nome as formando_nome, gf.nome as gf_nome, t.nome as t_nome ...
```

Answer (score 0):

gf.nome is not a column of your table/view grupo_formando, go back to it and check that you have spelled the column name correctly and that it does exist

Comment: i just correct the colunm and now i have another error and i just uodate the post

Answer (score 0):

You need to alias either `formando.nome` or `gf.nome` AS something else to avoid having two `nome` columns in your result set.

For example:

```
SELECT formando.nome AS nome_1...
```